# styling a list in a div

Tags: html, css

```css
div[data-cc-digits] {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

div[data-cc-digits][input] {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div data-cc-digits>
  <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----"></input>
  <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----"></input>
  <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----"></input>
  <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----"></input>
</div>
<!--closing for data-cc-digits-->
```

The data-cc-digits DIV should have a 2em top margin.
INPUT elements in the data-cc-digitsDIV should have a white color, 2em font size and line height, no border or background, and a right margin of 0.5em;

The error am getting is of the form "One or more of the INPUT elements in the "data-cc-digits" DIV does not have the specified CSS"

Comment: Where are you getting the  "One or more of the INPUT elements in the "data-cc-digits" DIV does not have the specified CSS" error from. HTML does no normally throw errors

Answer (score 1):

Try the below way. You need not put `[input]` to access the child element

```css
div[data-cc-digits] {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

div[data-cc-digits] input {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div data-cc-digits>
  <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----" />
  <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----" />
  <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----" />
  <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----" />
</div>
```

Comment: I just tried it. but it is still giving me this One or more of the INPUT elements in the "data-cc-digits" DIV does not have the specified CSS.

Comment: but, when you click `Run code snippet`, do you see this issue?

Comment: it did not, i am working on a coding challenge whenever i run it on their platform it gives me the error above.

Comment: @oludamilareolukotun , note that the HTML has changed as well as the CSS. `input` has no closing tag.

Comment: @oludamilareolukotun have edited the css, please check. Thanks to I'm Limit

Answer (score 0):

Due to @Nidhin Joseph 's Answer (I didnt have 50 rep I can't comment)

input **white color** you mean 
background? `background: white`
or 
text white? `color: white`

***I have add `maxlength="4"` may fit your work

```css
div[data-cc-digits] {
  margin-top: 2em;
  background-color: gray;
}

div[data-cc-digits] input {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
div[data-cc-digits].other input {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  border: none;
  background: white;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div data-cc-digits>
  <input type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" placeholder="----" />
  <input type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" placeholder="----" />
  <input type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" placeholder="----" />
  <input type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" placeholder="----" />
</div>
<div data-cc-digits class="other">
  <input type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" placeholder="----" />
  <input type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" placeholder="----" />
  <input type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" placeholder="----" />
  <input type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" placeholder="----" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

apply css like this:

```
 div[data-cc-digits]
    {
         margin-top: 2em;
    }
    div[data-cc-digits]inputs{
         font-size: 2em;
         color: white;
         line-height; 2em;
         border: none;
         background: none;
         margin-right: 0.5em;

    }
```